# Return an implementation of type-constrained interface from a function

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement a repository pattern in go 1.19 and hit a wall.

I have created a type constrained interface like this

```
type RepoData interface {
    model.Order | model.Product | model.Cart
}

type Repository[T RepoData] interface {
    Add(c context.Context, data T) error
    Get(c context.Context, key any) (T, error)
    Delete(c context.Context, key any) error
    Update(c context.Context, data T) error
}
```

I have defined a `ProductRepository` like this:

```
type MongoRepository[T repo_types.RepoData] interface {
    repo_types.Repository[T]
}

type ProductRepository interface {
    types.MongoRepository[model.Product]
}
```

I have a function which should instantiate a repository based on a custom type of mine. It's definition is:

```
func newMongoRepository[T types.RepoData](cfg types.Config, repoType types.RepositoryType) mongo_types.MongoRepository[T] {
    connectionTimeout := types.Timeout.Milliseconds()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), types.Timeout)
    defer cancel()
    qmgoCfg := &qmgo.Config{
        Uri:              cfg.Url,
        Database:         cfg.Database,
        Coll:             string(repoType),
        ConnectTimeoutMS: &connectionTimeout,
    }

    cli, err := qmgo.NewClient(ctx, qmgoCfg)
    if err != nil {
        panic("error creating a mongo repository: " + err.Error())
    }

    switch repoType {
    case types.Product:
        return product.NewProductMongoRepository(cli, cfg.Database)
    }

    return nil
}
```

But, it won't compile. I'm getting this error:

```
product.ProductRepository does not implement MongoRepository[T] (wrong type for Add method)
                have Add(c context.Context, data model.Product) error
                want Add(c context.Context, data T) error
```

Can someone tell me how to do the thing I want correctly? Is it even possible?

Comment: You can assert the return value, `return product.NewProductMongoRepository(cli, cfg.Database).(mongo_types.MongoRepository[T])` but this effectively throws away the type safety that generics provide

Comment: @blackgreen Yeah I don't wanna do that. I want the type safety. Is there a better solution to this type of problems?

Comment: not really, a generic interface can be implemented only by other generic types instantiated with the same type parameter. You should consider redesigning your code and use generics for stuff that actually behaves the same. As a matter of fact there isn't much use in having the intermediate interfaces `MongoRepository` and `ProductRepository` with concrete types